# How to position the tip arrow of bootstrap popover next to a text field- CSS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried the various answers from the other questions posted on stack overflow, but haven't found any luck yet in positioning the tip arrow of the bootstrap popover.
html:

```
<input type = "text" id="account_create"/>
```

js:

```
$('.popover').css({
       'top': $('#account_create').offset().top + 'px',
       'left': $('#account_create').offset().left +'px'
  }).fadeIn(300);
```

The above code for inlining the popover with the text field. however this is what im getting:

[image]

Ideally i would want to align the popover and the arrow next to the text field ( the first one), but it constantly keeps jumping next to the second text field.

Any ideas, suggestions on how this can be achieved??

Thanks~

Comment: Might it be that it only seems to be jumping donw? Top borders of the input and the popover are aligned correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply place both the input field and popover in the same div and give that div position relative and the popover position absolute then left 0

```
<div class="parent">
    <input>
    <div class="popover"></div>
</div> 

.parent { 
    position: relative:
}
.popover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```